# Changing database context before creating new database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have noticed on many examples that before `CREATE DATABASE` statement, there is part that changes database context.

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE DATABASE Sample;
GO
```

I wonder why is that because with or without it, in SQL Server Management Studio 17, database creates right where it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Often these examples are accompanied by (or are expected to be copied and pasted to a script with) *other* commands, such as a `DROP DATABASE` first (which can’t happen if you’re in the context of that database that you’re trying to drop and re-create).

There are a few commands that need to be run in `master`, but not a whole ton. This may just be a convention by habit rather than by reason, and in all honesty, it probably is the source of many mistaken deployments to `master` instead of a user database. I wrote a tip about this situation:

- [Cleaning up the SQL Server master database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4530/cleaning-up-the-sql-server-master-database/)

Comment: Thank you for answer and tips for making and keeping master database clean. I read your post and it was very helpful for future database administration.